# How To Use Latest Date As A Condition In Query

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a few table, and one of it is "peminjaman" which have "date" atribute type in it, which is "tarikhpemulangan" example="2019-07-23" . I want to select from "peminjaman" where the atribute "tarikhpemulangan" must already pass from today date. Please help me.

```
<?php

echo '<h4><script>
var dateObj = new Date();
var bulan = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1;//bulan 1-12
var hari = dateObj.getUTCDate();
var tahun = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();
newdate= hari + "-" + bulan + "-" + tahun;
document.write(newdate);
</script></h4>';

include 'capaian.php';

$query1 = "SELECT * FROM peminjaman INNER JOIN lulus ON 
peminjaman.nokppeminjam=lulus.nokppeminjam INNER JOIN peminjam ON 
peminjaman.nokppeminjam=peminjam.nokppeminjam WHERE tarikhpemulangan <= 
'newdate'";
$capai1 = mysqli_query($capaiDB, $query1);

?>
```

Comment: Just use `WHERE tarikhpemulangan <= NOW()`. Also you can't really mix javascript and php like that, it won't work.

Comment: Expanding on @Rikudou_Sennin comment, the reason it will not work, javascript is run client side in the browser, it has no access to the server to make use of php variables. You can output the javascript from from php with the required data but you cannot out put a php variable from javascript. You can however use ajax to execute a php script to obtain the data but you would need to decide for yourself whether this is the best use of resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add NOW function on the query
and we don't need JavaScript code.

```
 include 'capaian.php';
 $query1 = "SELECT * FROM peminjaman INNER JOIN lulus ON 
 peminjaman.nokppeminjam=lulus.nokppeminjam INNER JOIN peminjam ON 
 peminjaman.nokppeminjam=peminjam.nokppeminjam WHERE tarikhpemulangan <= 
 NOW()";
 $capai1 = mysqli_query($capaiDB, $query1);
```

Comment: Can you please try and let me know if still any issue

Comment: Thank you, I really apreciate it.